# Dynamic sheet name in source dataset: (Excel (Blob storage)) on Azure Data Factory. - Error: Please select a work sheet for your dataset

Tags: excel, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have multiple .xlsx-files in my blob storage and I need to copy them to my Azure SQL Database using Azure data Factory.
I want to keep one Source Dataset (Blob Storage -Excel).
So I added two parameters in the dataset.

File   (string): blabla.xlsx

Sheet  (string): blabla (name of the sheet in excel).
[Source Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EyKM.png)

If I go to copy data and details are already filled in, I got the following error:
'Please select a work sheet for your dataset'
[Copy data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHprB.png)

If I change the sheet name in hardcode: blabla. It will works, but then I cannot make use of a dynamic sheet name.
Does someone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass the sheet name as dynamic to the dataset, then you will have to have dataset parameter and a pipeline parameter and then pass sheet name value from pipeline parameter to dataset parameter as below:

[image]

Comment: Does this mean that you must know the sheet names before you ingest? No way to use the Metadata Look up or anything like that ? Fantastic way to comment btw.

Comment: Yes, in order pass then dynamically, you will have to know them up front, so that you can pass them from pipeline parameters to your dataset parameter.

Comment: Does the sheet name support the regex pattern?