# Azure DataFactory|| Copy Activtity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to copy a excel file with multiple tabs  from one folder to another in ADLs using copy activity in datafactory.I have selected excel dataset as source dataset and csv dataset as sink dataset with name of the tab to copy defined in the dataset properties.

I am getting below error while running the pipeline :

**Only formula cells have cached results Activity ID: 0d26511f-4f82-45df-9e92-62c78f3f02b6**

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you share the ADF copy activity json to know the properties you have configured for data source and sink.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to copy multiple worksheets of your excel file to ADLS using ADF Copy activity, if that is the case then you will have to pass the worksheet names dynamically to the source dataset and and use the same parameter to define the sink file name, this will help you copy multiple sheets of the same excel file to desired sink.

Fore more info please refer to similar conversation here: [Dynamic sheet name in source dataset: (Excel (Blob storage)) on Azure Data Factory. - Error: Please select a work sheet for your dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63120384/dynamic-sheet-name-in-source-dataset-excel-blob-storage-on-azure-data-facto)